# React doesn't change the height of main component on child component length change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with height of my website. My component has

```
height: 100vh;
```

property but there is a moment when child component becomes really long- in that case height doesn't change and component lands somewhere below on white background. Is there any way to let main component know he has to use new height? I'm adding image to show it better.

[image: length]

Code sample as requested:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Container id="maincontainer" maxWidth="xl" sx={{border: (theme) => `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,bgcolor: 'background.paper',boxShadow: 5}}>
        <div id="inputcontainer">
          <StepperForm
          ></StepperForm>
        </div>
        <div id="outputcontainer">
          <ThreeScene
          ></ThreeScene>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

css:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
  min-height: 100vh;
  
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

#maincontainer {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inputcontainer {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: left !important; 
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#outputcontainer {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

What bothers me too is that my navbar shadow is being hidden:

[image: shadow]

Comment: `overflow: auto`, or `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: @ZacharyHaber it did help but now it shows scroll on the right side. overflow-y:hidden; just makes the rest of content dissapear.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the code please, it's very difficult for people to help without knowing the structure and styles being applied

Comment: @deowk main post edited with code sample

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring **height to 100vh** every time. This makes page too big and your components rendered between them seperated by 100vh margin.dont use 100vh your page automatically set its height if you want you can do

```
height:'auto',
```

And also try to elaborate your question more. Like we can't help you in your **boxShadow** because we can't see the code of it, also add images that are understandable